# Maintaining translations for a Chrome extension

Tags: internationalization, google-chrome-extension

I'm thinking about using the internationalization support for Chrome extensions as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n.html).

The suggested way to make translations is to first create the English messages.json file, then copy it over and translate it into the given language.

My problem is that this works all right for the initial translation, but when there are already some translations and some changes happen in the extension I don't see an easy way to update the translations.

I guess I would need tools for these tasks:

- detect new untranslated strings
- detect strings changed in English that might need revision in other languages too
- detect strings not used anymore

I guess by keeping around the original English messages.json file and using diff tools I could do this by hand, but I was wondering if there are any tools that can help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try https://webtranslateit.com/.
We are using it.

Comment: It is probably too much for my small project, but at least it is free for that size. Selected it as the chosen answer because there is no better suggestion.